# Почему в Perl для строк отдельные операторы сравнения?

Tags: perl

По работе пришлось столкнутся с программированием на Perl'е, и я заметил такую нелогичную вещь:

```
[do somesthing] unless $a < $b;
```

Не будет работать, если $a и $b - строки, для них нужно писать lt, gt и прочее. А в чем тогда смысл использования знаков $ % @, если для правильной работы с переменными надо всё равно знать их тип более точно? Или это очередное специальное исключение чтобы *некоторым* программистам работалось лучше, а остальные сетовали на нелогичность?

Comment: `10 > 2`, но `"10" < "2"`.

Answer (score 4):

1. Не путайте теплое с мягким. Знаки $ % @ обозначают не тип, а структуру значения - скаляр, хеш, массив. С типизацией строка/число это никак не свзязано.
2. Весь вопрос в следующем: что больше, 100 или 20? А кто Вам сказал, что это числа? Определение типа значений на самом деле менее удобно, чем разные операции. С одной стороны определять тип для каждой переменной намного более трудоемко, а с другой стороны очень часто появляются задачи сравнить две переменные с типом строка как числа или две переменные типа число как строки. Посмотрите любую программу на Си, пхп, других языках, там Вы очень часто увидите конструкцию toInt(a) < toInt(b). В Perl'е это делается намного проще. Надо всего лишь принять правила игры.
3. На самом деле данный подход *действительно* удобен и очень логичен. Надо всего лишь понять его и принять. Тут писали про исторические причины появления разных операций и про то, что теперь уже менять Perl поздно. На самом деле никаких исторических причин нет. Разные операции введены осмысленно именно потому, что это фактически разные операции, и естественно никто не собирается этого менять. Если сравнивать с тем же Bash'ем, то в Perl'е значение операций lt,gt и <,> намеренно другое, чем в Bash'е (там lt,gt - числовые, а <,> - строковые).
4. **ВНИМАНИЕ!** Операция gt не делает *лексикографического* сравнения. Это операция *строкового* сравнения. Операция лексикографического сравнения хорошо отсортирует такие строки: 'картинка 100', 'картинка 20' (двадцать будет меньше ста). Не обращали внимания на сортировку имен файлов в винде? Так вот, операция gt этого не умеет.

Answer (score 3):

Сразу же оговорюсь, что ни разу в жизни ничего дельного не написал на Перле (хотя, в принципе, знаком с языком, особенно, в связи с регэкспами).

Я не знаю, есть там *на самом деле* типизация или нет, но совершенно очевидно, что эти операторы просто делают разные вещи:

- > — численное сравнение
- gt — лексикографическое сравнение

Вот пример:

```
  DB<16> print('11' < '2')

  DB<17> print('11' > '2') # число 11 больше числа 2 (хотя тип — строка)
1
  DB<19> print('11' gt '2')

  DB<18> print('11' lt '2') # строка '11' лексикографически меньше строки '2'
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, это сделано, чтобы не было путаницы. < и >  - это операторы для работы с числовыми данными, а строки не могут сравниваться так, будто это числа какие-то.

Comment: А зачем тогда вообще говорить, что нет строк и чисел, а есть только скаляры? Ввели бы еще значочки для них: типа ^string и #number

Comment: Ну, вы ведь знаете, что на самом деле это не совсем так, и что типы на самом деле всё-таки есть ;) Не случайно ведь строки складывать нельзя плюсом. Всё же нельзя выполнять арифметические операции со строками, если только эти строки не числа.

Comment: Ну потому я и говорю, что, получается, использование $ как символа скаляра не имеет смысла, а лучше их разделить(раз перловщиком так нравится перегружать код непонятными символами)

Comment: Ну, боюсь менять синтаксис перла несколько.. поздновато ;)

Comment: Я думаю и программировать на перле надо было прекратить лет 10 назад. Но меня никто не слушает Т_Т

Comment: Совершенно очевидно, что это сделано именно из-за того что это разные по своей сути операции сравнения. Вызвано ли это какими-то техническими ограничениями или такое решение было принято намеренно — думаю, знает только автор.

Comment: «PHP is a minor evil perpetrated and created by incompetent amateurs, whereas Perl is a great and insidious evil, perpetrated by skilled but perverted professionals». — Jon Ribbens

Comment: @saigono. опасные вы вещи говорите! Могут и под расстрел отдать :)

Comment: Это сделано для совместимости с sh. Изначально Perl был написан
как развитие sh, где большинство команд, аналогичных командам unix
были встроенными, что сильно повышало быстродействие.
Затем все развивалось, изменялось ... но ноги растут оттуда.

Comment: @kirelagin По сути, лексикографическое сравнение, это операция сравнения на множестве строк. То есть сравнение оно и в африке сравнение, зачем плодить лишнее.
@avp Спасибо, теперь понятно

Comment: @saigono затем, что, как уже верно было подмечено, perl — это, в некотором смысле, развитие sh. Соответственно строка там является основным типом (все аргументы программам ходят как строки). Так что желание сравнить две строки численно — абсолютно естественно (см. пример в моём ответе).

Comment: @kirelagin сравнивать строки численно - это абсолютно неестественно. Строки они на то и строки, чтобы сравнивать их лексикографически. А тянуть за собой костыли для обратной совместимости - это не выход. Но, к сожалению, не у всех программистов хватает смелости сказать, что с версии XXX конструкция YYY - deprecated, используйте ZZZ

Comment: @saigono так, я ещё раз повторю, что речь идёт о шелле, где всё-всё-всё, абсолютно всё передаётся в виде строк и очень (ОЧЕНЬ-ОЧЕНЬ) часто возникает необходимость сравнить две строки численно. Дело не в отсутствии смелости, а в удобстве. Да, в отличие от Питона, при разработке Перла на первом месте стояло удобство и краткость, а не высокие архитектурные цели.

Comment: @kirelagin Сравнить 2 строки не хочется численно. Хочется сравнить 2 числа, но так как чисел нет, то хочется сделать сравнение строк как будто бы они числа. И зачем только это современному perl'у? Удобство и краткость это хорошо, но общий вектор развития должен быть. Но к сожалению в перле я не могу его проследить

Comment: @saigono общий вектор развития Перла — оставаться Перлом. Потому что Питон и Руби уже есть.

Comment: Оставаться перлом - это означает оставаться нелогичным языком программирования? Окок

Comment: @saigono можете называть это так, если угодно ;).

Answer (score 0):

Строки сравнивать на больше или меньше тоже не логично =)

Comment: Слышали когда-нибудь про такую штуку как «лексикографический порядок»?

Comment: А вы её когда-нибудь применяли для строк, не для символов?)

Comment: При сортировке.

Comment: А Вы думаете её чисто по приколу придумали, без какого-либо практического применения?

Comment: чисто по приколу никто ничего не делает (=

Comment: Расскажите это составителям словарей. Хотя нет, лучше не рассказывайте...

Answer (score 0):

1. (lt, gt) vs (<, >) - в perlop (perldoc perlop или любая другая справочная система - раздел perlop) чётко написано:
   Binary "<" returns true if the left argument is numerically less than the right argument.
   Binary "lt" returns true if the left argument is stringwise less than the right argument.
2. $, @, % - это уже агрегатность данных: скаляр, список (операции над одномерными массивами, pop/push - shift/unshift и т.д.) и хэш-массивы (в других языках map, справочники и т.д.). К типу значений число/строка они отношения не имеют. Тем более, что типизация слабая динамическая и можно вполне писать $a = "001"; $b = $a +1; .

Сложилось это наверняка исторически, что-то унаследовано от shell'ов, что-то от C, что-то (напр. closures) даже от лиспа. И компот получился весьма оригинальный.
Но perl вдобавок оказал влияние и на другие скриптовые языки.

Comment: а что будет, если выполнить $a->(1); если $a - это строка? И соответственно, что будет, если выполнить substr $a -4; если $a - указатель на функцию?

Comment: Ругаться будет нехорошими английскими словами. "И это правильно." (c) М.С. Горбачёв

Comment: Ну и нафига такая агрегатность? :)

Comment: А какой результат должна выдавать substr от функции?
С таким подходом уж лучше язык brainfuck или ещё что-то из той же группы.
Perl и так многие считают write-only языком.

Answer (score 0):

А в случае сравнения числа со строкой -- что к чему приводить? А если у нас числа в составе большой пачки строковых данных сортируются?

Тут уже надо либо всегда явно приводить типы, либо делать как в перле или баше.

Answer (score 0):

В том-то и дело, что строгой типизации нет. Если бы она была, можно было бы обойтись едиными знаками для сравнения строк и чисел. А из-за того, что perl никогда не знает, что перед ним - строка или число - нужно использовать различные операторы для сравнения строк и чисел.

Comment: Как нет типизации? В Perl5 она вполне себе есть, вполне обычная динамическая типизация. Такая же, к слову, как в PHP, Python или Ruby.

Comment: Ок, не совсем правильно выразился - имел в виду, что нет строгого разделения между типами "число" и "строка", т.е. нет строгой типизации. Не стоит придираться к словам ;)

Comment: В этом и есть самая главная проблема: перл заставляет программиста следить за контекстом использования переменной, вместо того чтобы делать это самому.